# SYSTEM_USER in SQL Server 2016 returning different value than in SQL Server 2014 in case of Windows authentication

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using the SYSTEM_USER function to return the windows authentication user in SQL Server 2014. For the user *localMachine\localUser* value returned is *localMachine\localUser*.

However, in SQL Server 2016, the value returned is *MICROSOFTACCOUNT\user.name@OUTLOOK.COM*.

Value returned when using SQL Server Authentication is OK in both SQL Server versions.

I 've searched the documentation to try to find any possible reasons for this changed behavior, but couldn't find any.

Functions S_USERNAME and ORIGINAL_LOGIN behave in the same manner with Windows auth.

Thanks for any answers!